# Failure of Simplify in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, algebra

My question is about an apparent failure of Mathematica's function "FullSimplify" to simplify an easy algebraic expression.

This is the expression that I ask Mathematica to evaluate:

```
FullSimplify[Re[a^(I*b)] - Re[a^(-I*b)], Element[a, Reals] && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]]
```

This should give the result 0. Instead Mathematica only restates my expression:

```
Re[a^(-I b) (-1 + a^(2 I b))]
```

Replacing a and b by actual numbers solves the problem.

What could be the cause of it? How to effectively use FullSimplify (and Simplify, Expand, Integrate and so...)?

I read that the order of variables could play a role here, but I couldn't wrap my head around it.

I tried to check for similar problems on the website as well, but I couldn't find any answer that could explain this phenomenon.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Hi Giovanni, I think your question would be a better fit on the [mathematica.stackexchange.com](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @Sigroad What a blunder! I was actually unaware that such a site existed, thank you for your prompt reply though and sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: I "auto-migrated" the question to the correct website:
 
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85003/failure-in-the-use-of-fullsimplify